# Creating Collection with Class Objects

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to consolodate my code a bit by making the code a little more polymorphic.  I have a userform in which I have 5 tabs.  Each tab has 3 columns in which to place controls dynamically at run time.

I am looking to consolidate all of my Top and Left Positions for each control as i start building this form.

Right now I have variables like this.

```
Tab0StartFromTop
Tab1StartFromTop
Tab2StartFromTop
Tab3StartFromTop
Tab4StartFromTop

Tab0Col1Left
Tab0Col2Left
Tab0Col3Left
''you get the picture
```

What I'd like to do is something like this

```
Dim TabAttributes(0 To 4) As Collection
Dim ColumnAttributes As clsColumn ''clsColumn is a class object with properties for both .Top and .Left
Dim ColumnAttributeCollection As Collection

''Load Up my initial data. Distance from top will be incremented as I add controls
Set ColumnAttributes = New clsColumn
ColumnAttributes.Top = StartFromTop
ColumnAttributes.Left = StartFromLeft

''load all 3 objects into the (0) zero index for tab0
ColumnAttributeCollection(1).Add ColumnAttributes
ColumnAttributeCollection(2).Add ColumnAttributes
ColumnAttributeCollection(3).Add ColumnAttributes

''Now stick it inside my TabAttributes
TabAttributes(0).add ColumnAttributeCollection
```

so now I could access it like this, or in some way.

```
For each blah..
    TabAttributes(MyControl.Tabindex).Column(MyControl.ColumnIndex).Top
    TabAttributes(MyControl.Tabindex).Column(MyControl.ColumnIndex).Left
Next
```

also as I loop through each control I will need to adjust the top integer as more controls are added to that specific column on that specific tab.

```
TabAttributes(MyControl.Tabindex).Column(MyControl.ColumnIndex).Top = _
     TabAttributes(MyControl.Tabindex).Column(MyControl.ColumnIndex).Top + 40
```

I hope that makes sense.  Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: I think I missed the question somewhere along the line of reading this. Is there a reason you can't just use the `.Top` and `.Left` of the controls themselves? I'm not exactly sure what benefit there is to duplicating them.

Comment: Have a look at [Custom Collection Classes in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CollectionClass.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer using arrays over collections.  Perhaps something like this might work for you:

```
Const lTop As Long = 0      'Use named variable to always work with Top attribute
Const lLeft As Long = 1     'Use named variable to always work with Left attribute

Dim lTabIndex As Long
Dim aTabColumns() As Variant
ReDim aTabColumns(0 To 4, 0 To 1)
    'The first dimension (0 to 4) is for your tab numbers
    'The second dimension (0 to 1) shows if you're working with the Top or Left attribute for that tab's column
    'Example use:   aTabColumns(1, lTop) = aTabColumns(1, lTop) + 40

'Example showing how to loop through the array and set initial values
For lTabIndex = LBound(aTabColumns, 1) To UBound(aTabColumns, 1)
    aTabColumns(lTabIndex, lTop) = StartFromTop
    aTabColumns(lTabIndex, lLeft) = StartFromLeft
Next lTabIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work properly using a dictionary

```
Dim TabAttributes As Dictionary
Dim ColumnAttributes As Dictionary
Dim Column1Info As clsColumn
Dim Column2Info As clsColumn
Dim Column3Info As clsColumn
Dim TabColumnIndex As Integer

Set Column1Info = New clsColumn
Set Column2Info = New clsColumn
Set Column3Info = New clsColumn
Set TabAttributes = New Dictionary
Set ColumnAttributes = New Dictionary

'set column offsets
Column1Info.Left = StartFromLeft
Column1Info.Top = StartFromTop
Column2Info.Left = StartFromLeft + Column1Width + ColumnGap
Column2Info.Top = StartFromTop
Column3Info.Left = StartFromLeft + Column1Width + ColumnGap * 2 + Column2Width
Column3Info.Top = StartFromTop

'add column offsets to class object
ColumnAttributes.Add 1, Column1Info
ColumnAttributes.Add 2, Column2Info
ColumnAttributes.Add 3, Column3Info

'add class object to each tab index
For TabColumnIndex = 0 To 4
    TabAttributes.Add TabColumnIndex, ColumnAttributes
Next
```

So now I can get my data like this...

```
TabAttributes(MyControl.Tabindex)(MyControl.ColumnIndex).Top = 125
```

thanks for the help guys